# Relations between row and columns of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-analysis

Given a orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we know $Q^{\top}$ is also orthogonal. Let $Q$ represent a linear transformation from an Euclidean space to itself, then reading from the columns and the rows of the matrix $Q$, we obtain two sets of orthonormal basis.

> Are there any relations between these two sets of orthonormal basis either from the algebraic or geometric perspectives?

I cannot think of anything concrete. Perhaps $Q^{2}$ tells us something?

Comment: $Q^TQ=I$ since $Q^T=Q^{-1}$. Can you see what this implies about the basis vectors?

Comment: See the concept of dual bases [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139541/305862).

Comment: Dual bases are also mentionned in this interesting [online book](https://www.edp-open.org/images/stories/books/fulldl/Introduction_to_Louis_Michels_lattice.pdf
)

Comment: @JeanMarie I know what dual bases are. Given the columns of Q as the basis, in this case, the rows of $Q^{-1} = Q^T$ are the dual basis. However, the rows of Q^T, are just the columns of Q. Can you elaborate, perhaps I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: The dual basis is the basis.